# PyQT6 hidden sidebar(main-menu) showed up with mouseover

Tags: python, pyqt6

I want to make a menu bar which is located at the left side of the MainWindow() in PyQT6 but not using QMenuBar. And I want to make the bar be animated with mouseover so that is can be hidden before the cursor is hovered on it. But I totally don't know how to make it. Please!

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    central_widget = QWidget(self)

    layout_main = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

    layout_menubar = QVBoxLayout()

    button_names = ['notice', 'dash', 'courses', 'users']
    buttons = []

    for name in button_names:
        button = QPushButton(name)
        buttons.append(button)
        layout_menubar.addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, name=name: self.button_selected(name))

    layout_main.addLayout(layout_menubar)
    layout_main.addWidget(QPushButton('This is MAIN'))

    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

def button_selected(self, name):
    print(f"{name} selected")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("PyQT6 test")
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```